# VS 2022 bug ? I'm using .Net 7 Blazor and VS studio shows at same time two different date values in one object

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, ide

This problem is a bit hard for me to tell but very easy to show. In pictures below you can see DateTime variable and assigned to it value from another variable. IDE shows other date when mouse is on variable and in properties tree. Also assigned date is one from tree but when compared in if statement the date is proper one (the one inside properties). Anyone had similar problem?

I tested it by assigning values to new DateTime object, always same in IDE (as above) and always new value was proper.

Stackoverflow got some problems and I can't paste image so here is url:
https://i.postimg.cc/RSxq27R7/2nddate.png

Here is almost whole code:
HTML PART

```
<AuthorizeView Context="Auth">
<RadzenTemplateForm TItem="Reservation" Data="@resModel" Submit=@OnSubmit onclose="CloseModal">
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 16px">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <RadzenLabel Text="Title" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <RadzenTextBox Disabled=!CanEdit @bind-Value="@resModel.Title" Name="Title" />
        <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Title is required" Component="Title" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 16px">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <RadzenLabel Text="Start" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <RadzenDatePicker Disabled=!CanEdit @bind-Value="@resModel.Start" Name="Start" ShowTime="true" />
        <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Start is required" Component="Start" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 16px">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <RadzenLabel Text="End" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <RadzenDatePicker Disabled=!CanEdit Name="End" @bind-Value="@resModel.End" ShowTime="true" />
        <RadzenRequiredValidator Component="End" Text="End is required" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 16px">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <RadzenLabel Text="Description" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <RadzenTextArea  Disabled=!CanEdit  @bind-Value="@resModel.Description" Name="Description" Style="height:200px; width: 300px"/>
        <RadzenRequiredValidator Text="Description is required" Component="Description" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col">
        <RadzenButton  Disabled=!CanEdit ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" Text="Save" />
    </div>
</div>
```

```
@code {
[Parameter]
public DateTime Start { get; set; }
[Parameter]
public DateTime End { get; set; }
[Parameter]
public int Id { get; set; }
[Parameter]
public bool CanEdit { get; set; }

Reservation resModel = new Reservation();
User? user;
[CascadingParameter]
private Task<AuthenticationState>? authenticationState { get; set; }
ClaimsPrincipal claims = null;

protected override void OnParametersSet()
{
    resModel.Start = AddDefaultHoursToDateStart(Start);
    resModel.End = AddDefaultHoursToDateEnd(End);
}

void OnSubmit(Reservation reservationModel)
{
    var resEnd = reservationModel.End;
    var resStart = reservationModel.Start;
    if (reservationModel.End < resStart)
    {
        NotificationService.Notify(new NotificationMessage { Severity = NotificationSeverity.Error, Summary = "You can't end before start &#1F605!" });
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Talking about code and pictures does not help without code and pictures. Code preferred.

Comment: Updated, there is some issue from stackoverflow ('server error') while posting image.

Comment: @Ralf - I'm not sure if you got notified :P

Comment: If you look in the Threads tool panel (debug>>windows>>threads) when the code is stopped on that breakpoint, do you see multiple threads stopped at the same point? What does resEnd show as a value in tooltip? Is there any way that evaluating the value of reservationModel.End property can change its value?

Comment: @Ralf this query kinda needs the image though

Comment: @Ossj Local is correct but the End variable content you get to see in the tooltip is from a different End. Like the one from resModel.End? That tooltip somethimes get "confused"    when opening it and scrolling sourcecode.

Comment: @HasBeanCounter yes but did you need that before having the image ;)

Comment: Did I need the image before I had the image? I think yes, but I'm not sure if I understood the question as posed. I'm not even sure if it was intended as a question - it reads like one but lacks a mark!